# No output with #PBS scipts

Tags: php, bash, output, echo, pbs

Here's my #PBS script:

```
#PBS -N echotest
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -q batch
#PBS -o /home/wordir/echo
#PBS -e /home/wordir/echo
nodes=$(cat $PBS_NODEFILE)
nprocs='cat $PBS_NODEFILE|wc  -I'

echo "Nodes allocated in job $PBS_JOBID"
echo "---------------------------------"
echo "$nodes"
echo "Task begins at `date`" 
echo "Staring job $PBS_JOBID on $(hostname)"
echo "------------end------------------"

cd /home/wordir/echo
nohup rfluka -N0 -M1 input &
```

After `qsub echo.pbs`, No output information of echo command on screen, and no output/error files within the `/home/wordir/echo` directory, wonder why ?

After `qsub echo.pbs` and `qstat -n`, noticing JOB State change form "R" to "C" in just few seconds. And no corresponding files in `/home/wordir/echo` directory. I doubt the program is not submitted successfully. Am I right?

I separately tested the 'nohup rfluka -N0 -M1 input &*' on terminal, and it works fine, there are output files in this directory.

Can anyone points the wrongs with this #PBS scripts?

Comment: the program should run at least minutes.